# Unable to Provide Input for a MultiValue Parameter Script Tool

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, arctoolbox, parameters

I have the following script:

```
#Import ArcPy site package
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy import Raster
from arcpy.sa import ZonalStatistics
from arcpy.sa import CreateConstantRaster

# Set Environment Workspace
ws = env.workspace = "MY_WORKSPACE_PATH\\FGD.gdb"
# Set Environment Raster Cell Size
env.cellSize = 10

# Check out ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Get Parameters as Text
rasters = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inputRasters = rasters.split(";")
inZoneData = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
zoneField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

# The constant raster = 0
addedRaster = CreateConstantRaster(0)

# Process each raster string
for raster in inputRasters:
    addedRaster = addedRaster + Raster(ws + "\\" + raster)

# Execute Zonal Statistics
zoneStats = ZonalStatistics(inZoneData, zoneField, addedRaster, "MAXIMUM", "DATA")

# Save the output
zoneStats.save(ws + "\\" + NewTest_12102011")
```

I have imported the script as a script tool in ArcMap, my parameters are in the correct order and have the correct attributes (this script works when I have, for example, just two raster inputs as parameters). The input rasters are referenced as a String (this tool will eventually be used as a Geoprocessing Task, so I cannot use rasters a input directly). The problem I have is that when I open the tool, there is no way for me to input anything into the first parameter.

[image]

*To provide some clarity:* each value that could be entered into the parameter would be the name of a raster inside the geodatabase. For instance, say the user enters "rasterOne" and "rasterTwo". This would refer to MY_WORKSPACE_PATH\FGD.gdc\rasterOne and MY_WORKSPACE_PATH\FGD.gdc\rasterTwo, which are then cast to a Raster object with

```
Raster("MY_WORKSPACE_PATH\\FGD.gdc\\rasterOne")
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Have you ruled out the ListRasters method as shown in the online help topic? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001s000000

Comment: @DanPatterson I have ruled that out. I don't want to input every raster in the work space/GDB, nor provide a list of available rasters. As mentioned, this will eventually be a Geoprocessing Task running on ArcServer. In a Flex application, a user would select a check box with a corresponding ID attribute. This ID attribute would correspond to a raster in the GDB, say id="rasterOne". This is pushed into an array and provided as a parameter in execute/submitJob. The array might be params = ["rasterOne", "rasterTwo"]. Similar to this example:

Comment: @DanPatterson example link: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html#/Asynchronous_geoprocessing_Clip_and_ship/01nq0000006t000000/

Comment: Not sure about Flex, but in arctoolbox you can provide a Filter option, which defaults to None, if you specify Value List, you could put the names of the rasters in there and they should show in a checklist form (if memory serves).

Comment: @DanPatterson Scratch that, I found it. Does this provide the functionality to allow the user to select more than one value from the value list?

Comment: Really frustrating, this is STILL a bug 7 years later at version 10.6!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the following workflow to work:

1. Create a model and drag my script tool into it.
2. Create a variable, and check the "Multivalue" checkbox.
3. Link the variable and the script tool with the connector tool, and choose for it to be a parameter from the script tool, i.e. in my case a string of rasters

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above comments, I will show what this simple script and the toolbox with a filter list allows and you can decide if that is the desired outcome.
The following script

```
import arcpy
selected= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.AddMessage("\nselected data " + str(selected) + "\n")
```

was added to a toolbox with one multivalue parameter with values provided to be selected.  The following image shows the input stage with 3 string values selected (eg names of input data for example)
[image: multivalue selection]

The following is the output.

```
Executing: Multiparameter first;second;third
Start Time: Mon Dec 12 10:57:45 2011
Running script Multiparameter...

selected data first;second;third

Completed script Multiparameter...
Succeeded at Mon Dec 12 10:57:45 2011 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)
```

Not sure if that helps, but it might useful for other posts.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the visual example. Did you provide the values through the Import Script Tool or in the script itself?\

Comment: When defining the tool parameters, the "Filter" option allows you to switch from None to a Value List and you can enter the values there.  You may be able to use SetParameterAsText to define them within a script, but I haven't played with that option.

Comment: Your suggestion worked and I found where to input those values. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in arcmap to me.  You could just take a single-value string input, comma separated, and split it:

```
list_of_strings = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0).split(',')
```

Comment: That's how I originally had the code (I took it from the Clip and Ship tutorial data, but when I opened the script they used in the model it was from 9.3, and I am running 10.0). Even so, shouldn't it work just the same the way I have it now? Or would you recommend removing the extra variable and just adding it to the end of 'rasters'?