# Creating list of strings as parameter to Python script tool?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, parameters

I am trying to have a list of strings to pass as parameter to my script:

[image]

when I start the script it displays:

[image]

With "Add Value' button disabled. What am I missing here?

Comment: There is 'solution' by adding Filter-Value List, but it is ugly

Comment: I was thinking that you wanted to enter multiple free format strings rather than choosing them from a list.  Tool validation may be of assistance but will still not be pretty.

Comment: Yes I do want free format strings, using Value List was just an interim solution and I don't like it. This is about fixing missing paths in old mxds anyway

Comment: I've not done this but perhaps it can work.  Use a second parameter to enter a single value string parameter and use tool validation to use that being entered to trigger update of your separate multi value string parameter.

Comment: There appears to be another approach that incorporates ModelBuilder at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17821/unable-to-provide-input-for-a-multivalue-parameter-script-tool  It seems a little unintuitive but sounds like it may work and be simpler than tool validation.

Comment: Yes it is a workaround with model builder, I like it. It seems my Q is duplicate. Still don't understand why ESRI did it to string variable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "Any Value" data type instead of the "String" data type. I have no idea why multivalue strings don't work, but it's very counterintuitive...

[image: Script properties]
[image: Script tool GUI]

Comment: I am accepting this although it was one of the solutions I've checked. I was looking for true string inputs because they are not enclosed in ' symbols, even if there are \ symbols inside the string. This is convenient when working with folders (non-existing things from old mxds)