# Python multivalue list to script

Tags: arcpy, multi-values, value-list

I have some scripts that make symbology for different layers in my TOC.
And now I want to merge them into one big script which should have parameters chosen by user to start certain part of script.
For instance I have three layers: GGG, DDD, DDA. The whole script contains code to make symbology for all these layers.
But is it possible to make something like this?

[image]

If box "DDD" is checked script run the part of it which will paint only DDD layer.
If it is possible what kind of code I should add to script?

Updated code:

```
for s in selected:
    if selected == "DDD": 
        arcpy.AddMessage("Making a DDD")
        ary = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"\\SRV-NAS-03\Projects\FIAS_MultiPART.lyr")
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer (df,ary,"AUTO_ARRANGE")

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

It is taken from this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/17824/77806) to [Unable to Provide Input for a MultiValue Parameter Script Tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17821)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the values checked in the `inputdata` parameter using this code:

```
import arcpy
all_selected = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
selected = all_selected.split(";")

for s in selected:
    if s == "DDD": 
        arcpy.AddMessage("Making a DDD")
    # ...
```

See [Setting script tool parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm) for reference.

Comment: According to my case it should be like: `for s in selected:
    if selected == "DDD":
    arcpy.AddMessage ("Making a DDD")` But python kicks an error

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `IndentationError: expected an indented block (multivalue.py, line 8)` Line 8 is arcpy.AddMessage ("Making a DDD")

Comment: Says what it says, check your indentation. Write your script in an editor to get your syntax checked. I've edited my code to match your workflow

Comment: Just replaced. Now it is without errors, however, do nothing if I tick DDD. No messages and adding of symbology layers. Identation is okay.

Comment: Strange, just tested and it works fine for me. Could you post your updated code?

Comment: Update in description

Comment: Just print the values in `selected` to try to sort this out: `for s in selected: arcpy.AddMessage(s)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50011/discussion-between-pavel-pereverzev-and-gisge).